# How to compare Thread.currentThread() to a saved Thread reference? ==, equals, ..?

Tags: java

I am writing a class which queues up the operations from its other methods into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, and then has a process() method which should be called only from the creating thread, which processes the queue. This is because the operations from the other methods can be called from other threads, but their actual actions should only be executed on the creator thread. This is akin to Android's [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) which must be used to run any UI code outside of the UI thread.

My idea for the process method is to first assert that the creator thread is calling it, and then simply run each thing in the queue. I'm unsure about how to compare the current thread to the stored Thread reference; I can't find documentation about whether the references are guaranteed to be the same. Should I use the `equals` method? Should I just use the `==` operator? Can Thread objects even be compared, or should I be comparing their names or some other piece of data?

The relevant bit of code will look something like this: (queue logic not shown)

```
public class MultiThreadTasker {
    private Thread creatorThread;

    public MultiThreadTasker() {
        creatorThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    public void process() {
        if(Thread.currentThread() != creatorThread) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Recommendations for alternative ways to do this would also be welcome. It seems like I'm reinventing an Executor, but I didn't see any sort of Executor that lets you manually kick off the running of the tasks instead of it handling its own thread(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want tasks to be executed on the current thread why do they share a queue at all? I would have a queue local to each thread which only that thread can see/use.

This is what I would do.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Queue<Runnable>> QUEUE = new ThreadLocal<Queue<Runnable>>() {
    @Override
    protected Queue<Runnable> initialValue() {
        return new LinkedList<Runnable>(); 
    }
};

public static void runLater(Runnable runnable) {
    QUEUE.get().add(runnable);
}

public static void runAll() {
    for (Runnable runnable : QUEUE.get())
        runnable.run();
    QUEUE.get().clear();
}
```

Comment: The tasks are submitted into the queue from other threads, but these tasks can only be run on the thread which creates this object. It's a producer/consumer relationship, not a delayed task runner.

Comment: So the lifecycle is; a thread creates a task, another thread takes this task and adds it to a queue without having any idea which thread created it, the first thread runs the task?

Comment: The lifecycle is: the main thread creates an instance of this queue wrapper, then it passes it into an async method call which runs on a child thread. The child thread makes calls on the wrapper which put Runnables into the queue (I didn't include these methods in my code in the question). Then once the async task is done (the child thread is done putting things into the Runnable queue), the main thread calls process() and those tasks are executed on the main thread.

Comment: But the main thread creates the tasks as well other wise you couldn't process them on the main thread. So what does the child thread do other than add the tasks the main thread created?

Comment: "the main thread creates the tasks as well other wise you couldn't process them on the main thread" -> Huh? You can certainly process a runnable from a different thread... Anyway I've discovered a bigger problem (the async callback is called from the child thread) so this solution can no longer apply to my particular situation. So unfortunately I'm just going to close this question. Edit: okay, apparently I can't close or delete it... weird...

Comment: "You can certainly process a runnable from a different thread." I thought the whole point of this question is to prevent this. I am confused.

Comment: It sounds to me like you were asserting that a Runnable may only be run on the thread that creates the Runnable. I was stating that it is technically possible for one thread to create a Runnable, store it somewhere, and another thread takes it and runs it. And following this, I was trying to create a Runnable in a child thread, store it in the thread-safe queue, and run it later in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If comparing threads doesn't work, you could use a thread local UUID (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to compare invokers. You would populate your thread local field in the constructor.