# How to compare thread objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I recently came across the sources of AWT's [`EventQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) where I saw this piece of code:

```
final boolean isDispatchThreadImpl() {
    EventQueue eq = this;
    pushPopLock.lock();
    try {
        EventQueue next = eq.nextQueue;
        while (next != null) {
            eq = next;
            next = eq.nextQueue;
        }
        if (eq.fwDispatcher != null) {
            return eq.fwDispatcher.isDispatchThread();
        }
        return (Thread.currentThread() == eq.dispatchThread);
    } finally {
        pushPopLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

What really struggles me is that the thread objects are being compared using `==`. So far I've been doing this with `equals(Object)`. I already had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12353193/3429133) but the two answers aren't really what I'm looking for.

Is it possible that two different instances refer to the same native thread? How should I compare thread objects for equality?

Comment: Heh, one of those amusing situations where the *question* is indeed a duplicate, but the answers there don't answer the question asked. :-)

Comment: The key to your question is whether `Thread.currentThread() == eq.dispatchThread` will ever give you a different result than `Thread.currentThread().equals(eq.dispatchThread)`. And the answer is no, it never will, because [`Thread.currentThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--) will never return `null` and `Thread` inherits `equals` from `Object`, and [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) does `==`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was thinking the same thing! ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible that two different instances refer to the same native thread?

No.

According to the `Thread` javadoc:

> A *thread* is a thread of execution in a program.

The life cycle of a `Thread` object has three phases:

- Prior to the `start()` call, a `Thread` object denotes a *thread* that has yet to be created.  And might never be created; i.e. if `start()` isn't called.  (At this point, there is no native thread.)
- After the `start()` call, and until the `run()` call terminates, the `Thread` object denotes a live *thread*. (At this point, there is a native thread.)
- After the `run()` call terminates, the `Thread` object denotes a *thread* that no longer exists.  (At this point the native thread that embodied the *thread* has been deleted.)

At no point does it make any sense for two distinct `Thread` objects to denote the same *thread*; i.e. the same thread of execution.

> How should I compare thread objects for equality?

You can use either `==` or `equals(Object)`.  They are equally correct.  `Thread` inherits `equals` from `Object` where it is defined to be the same as `==`.

---

On the point of style.

Some would argue that is is stylistically better to use `equals`.  I have no strong opinion one way or another on that.

BUT, this question wasn't about style.  It was (in essence) about whether `==` is semantically correct in this context.  And it is.

Comment: Thread t1 = new Thread(); Thread t2 = new Thread(); System.out.println(t1.equals(t2)); Can we do this? Means can we compare two thread references pointing to an object? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do it.  As my answer says, `==` and `equals` are both correct ways of testing if two threads are the same.  (In your example, the output will be `false`, because `t1` and `t2` are different threads.)

Answer (score 2):

The first key thing here is: **there can't be two threads that would be equal but have different references**.

So in essence: this is one of the rare cases where using the check for equal references makes sense. Especially in a case where it is not about comparing an "arbitrary high" number of thread objects. You just one to make sure that the "current" thread is (not) some thread reference you stored earlier on.

Of course, one could also use `equals(Object)` to compare threads, and maybe that would be better to avoid to surprise readers. But on the other hand, this would be more of a "style" question; regarding an aspect that probably is not very common for 99% of the code that you read/write in your daily life.

And, as TJ Crowder correctly points out: `Thread.equals(Object)` translates to `Object.equals(Object)`, which ... does a simple check for reference equality. Underlying the point that this is really style only. Which holds true, until people would start creating their own sub-classes of Thread and provide a **different** implementation of equals.

Finally, the second key thing is: **two Java thread objects can not have the same underlying native threads**.

Answer (score 1):

From [JSL-17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html):

> These threads independently execute code that operates on values and
>   objects residing in a shared main memory

It means that each instance of thread will be executing independently of other instances, although the data can be shared between them. So, two instances cannot refer to same native thread.

As a general case, you should prefer `equals(Object)` for checking equality. But for `Thread` equality, you can use either `==` or `equals(Object)` method.

Source code of `Thread.equals(Object)` inherited from `java.lang.Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```