# c# Thread.Equals vs Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId comparison

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

In a piece of code I'm currently refactoring there is a dictionary with saved threads.
Now, inside a `lock` block i'm comparing the current thread with the ones saved in the dictionary with

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(id) && dictionary[id] != null &&
    Thread.CurrentThread.Equals(dictionary[id].OwnerThread))
{
    release(...);
}
```

Now I would like to replace the `Equals()` with
`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == dictionary[id].OwnerThread.ManagedThreadId`

More specifically, can ever Thread.Equals return false while a ManagedThreadId comparison would be true (for the same thread) ?

Comment: *or are these two comparable* they are not ... [`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.Equals(dictionary[id].OwnerThread)`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZL9yqA) always return `false` (I assume that `OwnerThread` is a `Thread` class) ... did you copy it wrong? and you have `Thread.CurrentThread.Equals(Thread.CurrentThread)`

Comment: @Selvin, thanks for pointing that out. Typo while copy pasting, I've corrected the question.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972629/how-to-compare-thread-objects) seems like an answer.

Comment: @FarhadGh, Even though that's a similar question I wouldn't make the assumption that Java behaves the same as C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways of checking for equality are *not* comparable.

`Equals` for a `Thread` is going to be a reference equals, because `Thread` is a class that doesn't override this behavior. The managed thread ID is just a comparison of integers.

I wouldn't worry about performance. I'd say you're right to use the managed thread ID for comparison as that is more correct. Note, though, that it is possible for you to later get a thread that was created with the same ID as a previous thread (assuming that previous thread no longer exists).